# Enforcing Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule

I have a custom field called Zip Code (Zip_Code__c). Data Type is number and the limit on digits is 5. I wanted to take it exactly 5 digits. But even if I give it 1 to 4 digits, it is accepting it. How do I write a validation rule for accepting exactly 5 digits and not more or less than 5 digits. Please help me.

I am stuck up here.

```
NOT(
 OR(

  REGEX(Zip_Code__c, "[0-9]{5}")
 )
)
```

Comment: What efforts have you made so far?

Comment: Also are you sure you do not want to account for full area codes (9 digit and a hyphen)? How about Canadian area codes which have letters?

Comment: I am looking on area codes just in USA.

Comment: Can you edit your current validation rule into the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a number field you should not worry about validating that the input is number only, the field will do that for you. Your primary concern is ensuring the length of input is equal to 5 digits.

```
LEN(TEXT(Zip_Code__c)) <> 5
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it say the following error, " Incorrect parameter type for function 'LEN()'. Expected Text, received Number"

Comment: See my updated formula